# Suspected Virus. Interuppted downloads on IE, Chrome, windows update, adobe

Tags: download, virus, malware, windows-10-preview

So I'm looking for some advice. I'm running out of ideas.

I have an issue on 2 of my computers. 
My MS Surface Pro 4, and Desktop PC. Downloads are interrupted in chrome and IE... Windows update is failing to download updates. Adobe Creative cloud cannot update...

I suspect a virus or malware. however I'm running Bitdefender on both (could this be the cause). I've also run malwarebytes. (Although I had to download on another computer, as it is showing a network error when downloading on either of these devices) Nothing is turning up any issues. I've tried Bitdefenders Repair CD to do an offline scan. I couldn't get Kaspersky or Windows defender to boot on my surface to try offline scans with them.

I have brought my surface to my office, and used the guest wifi. same issue so not the network.

Both computers are running windows 10 insider preview builds, but one is home(build 14942), one is pro (build 14959).

Any suggestions of what I can try? Any software I can run to narrow down the search area?

Thanks in advance

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was bitdefender... I'm guessing some incompatibility with one of the insider builds of windows. Uninstalled 2016, and installed 2017. all working again now!